# Evaluate the Lebesgue integrals:

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Throughout this problem the integrals written are Lebesgue integrals.

1. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{ne^x}{1+n^2\sqrt{x}}dx$
2. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 n\log(1+\frac{x^3}{n})dx$
3. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \int_1^2 (\log(x))^ndx$

Here is my attempt at these integrals.

1. As $n \rightarrow \infty$ we see that for every $x \in [0,1]$ we have $\frac{ne^x}{1+n^2\sqrt{x}} \rightarrow 0$. Then for every $n$ and a.e. x we see that$|\frac{ne^x}{1+n^2\sqrt{x}}| \leq \frac{e}{\sqrt{x}}$ which is integrable over $[0,1]$. Then by Dominating Convergence Theorem is the integral just equal to $0$?
2. For this one I think that the integrand tends to $x^3$ but I am having a hard time coming up with a dominating function. Any help would be appreciated.
3. I think this one is neat (if I did it correctly). We have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} \int_1^2 (\log(x))^n dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_1^2 \frac{1}{n!} (\log(x))^n dx,$$
   notice that the integrand is nonnegative so by Monotone Convergence Theorem we can put the summation inside: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_1^2 \frac{1}{n!} (\log(x))^n dx = \int_1^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\log(z))^n}{n!} dx= \int_1^2 e^{\log(x)} dx = \int_1^2x dx = 1.5$$

Please correct any mistakes that you see, thank you!

Comment: For $2$) the integrand does not approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: @Loobear23 - right sorry about that I think it approaches $x^3$.

Comment: Not sure why you say "also" in 2.

Comment: @zhw. - I have many typos I am very sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

For 2. note that $\ln(1+u)\le u$ for $u\ge 0.$ Thus a dominating function here is $x^3.$